# How do I generate unique random numbers in c#

Tags: c#, random

Hello guys I'm creating a program called Quiz game. Now my problem is how can I generate a non repeating questions? All of my questions is stored in a switch statement. I've tried and searched all of the possible solutions but still I get the same output. My code below is just a sample i didnt paste it all bcoz its too long. Whenever I call the method Question() it will random but sometimes the question that is already ask is being ask again.

```
    public void Question()
    {

     var random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        var randomValue = random.Next(1, 8);
        switch (randomValue)
        {
            case 1:
     ans = 1;

                    btnA.Visible = true;
                    btnB.Visible = true;
                    btnC.Visible = true;
                    btnD.Visible = true;
                    btn50.Enabled = true;
                    btndoubledip.Enabled = true;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "1+1=?";
                    voice = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                    voice.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Child);
                    voice.SpeakAsync(lblQuestion.Text.ToString());

                    btnA.Text = "2";
                    btnB.Text = "1";
                    btnC.Text = "4";
                    btnD.Text = "5";


                }
                break;
```

Comment: I dont even think your posted code will compile.

Comment: You're really thinking about this in the wrong way. First don't use a switch statement - keep your questions in a `List`, order the list randomly (plenty of ways to do that on Stack Overflow) and then just go through them in the new order.

Comment: You're going to need to somehow store the list of questions already asked. Or store a list of questions and remove items from it before choosing another one.

Comment: @maccettura its just a sample dude I just paste my method called Question()

Comment: @DavidG but is it okay to put that in a method like my public void Question()?

Comment: To give some intuition for what @DavidG said: if you're playing a card game, you don't randomly generate cards and make sure you haven't already drawn them; instead, you take a deck of cards and randomly shuffle it.  Imagine your questions as if it were a game with the questions printed on cards that you draw from a randomized deck and that should help you visualize how to model the game in terms of objects.

Comment: You may be falling prey to the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) here. If you generate random numbers from 1 to 7, there's a 1 in 7 chance that the next random number will be the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273313/7607408) to shuffle the list. So:

```
private static Random rng = new Random(); 
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) 
{ 
    int n = list.Count; 
    while (n > 1)
    {
          n--;
          int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
          T value = list[k]; 
          list[k] = list[n]; 
          list[n] = value; 
     } 
}
```

Then just shuffle your list of questions and display them from beginning to end.

```
List<Question> questions = new List<Question>()
{
    question1, 
    question2, 
    question3
    //... 
}
questions.Shuffle();
foreach (Question question in questions) question.Ask();
```

Comment: Fisher-Yates shuffle incase anybody wants to read more about the algorithm, its pretty cool!